# Select record using rownum in Oracle with nested subquery resulting invalid identifier error

Tags: sql, oracle, join, subquery, case

Following query is giving me invalid identifier error (a.id) because it is inside nested subquery:

```
SELECT a.*, 
CASE WHEN
SELECT id FROM (SELECT id, ROWNUM rnum FROM US b WHERE b.id = a.id ORDER BY b.createdate ASC) WHERE rnum = 2) = 21 THEN ‘Found’
END SEARCH
FROM EU a 
JOIN US b ON b.id = a.id;
```

Can anyone suggest me alternate approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't described much of your set-up or what you are trying to achieve but will this solve it?

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/cef96/1)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE EU ( id ) AS
SELECT 19+LEVEL
FROM   DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 5;

CREATE TABLE US ( id, createdate ) AS
SELECT 19+LEVEL, SYSDATE - LEVEL
FROM   DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 5
UNION ALL
SELECT 19+2*LEVEL, SYSDATE-LEVEL-5
FROM   DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 3;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT a.*,
       CASE WHEN a.id = 21
             AND ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY a.id ORDER BY b.createdate ) = 2
            THEN 'Found'
             END AS SEARCH
FROM   EU a 
JOIN   US b
ON     b.id = a.id
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/cef96/1/0)**:

```
| ID | SEARCH |
|----|--------|
| 20 | (null) |
| 21 | (null) |
| 21 |  Found |
| 22 | (null) |
| 23 | (null) |
| 23 | (null) |
| 24 | (null) |
```

Answer (score 0):

One problem with your query is the lack of paren before the second `SELECT`.  I still don't think it will work, because Oracle limits the scope of an identifier to one layer deep.  But this is what I think you intend:

```
SELECT a.*, 
       (CASE WHEN (SELECT id
                   FROM (SELECT id, ROWNUM as rnum
                         FROM US b
                         WHERE b.id = a.id
                         ORDER BY b.createdate ASC
                        )
                   WHERE rnum = 2
                  ) = 21 THEN ‘Found’
        END) SEARCH
FROM EU a JOIN
     US b
     ON b.id = a.id;
```

The easiest way to get what you want is to use `row_number()`:

```
select a.*,
       (case when b.id = 21 then 'Found' end) as Search
from eu a left join
     (select b.*,
             row_number() over (partition by b.id order by b.createddate) as seqnum
      from us b
     ) b
     on b.id = a.id
where seqnum = 2;
```

The query seems strange because `id` is used for everything.  You seem to be looking for two records on id 21.